# track content type from postman using content type header in postman

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I developed 2 mule flows of json and xml transformations to print first and last name..i am combining both flows using choice..now in postman I want to get individual output by setting header key as content-type, value as application/json or application/xml..how to set that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access these query parameters in dataweave and transform it to json. Then using the set payload message processor, you can return the output to postman. Just make sure you set the mimeType as application/json or application/xml, as per you requirement in the set payload message processor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a response transformer as below, But the best way is to use RAML which will make your job easy and you don't need a choice component

```
<response>
  <message-properties-transformer>
    <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
  </message-properties-transformer>
</response>

<response>
  <message-properties-transformer>
    <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="application/xml" />
  </message-properties-transformer>
</response>
```